# Run an html form in Eclipse PHP

Tags: php, html, eclipse

**If I try to run form.html through "Open with -> web browser", the html page itself displays fine, but clicking on the submit button leads to the raw code of form.php.**

[image][image][image]

**Now if I run form.php the normal way (ctrl + F11), it just runs the php code and ignores the html page that was supposed to run before it.**

[image]

**So what do I do in order to get BOTH the html form and the onsubmit php file to run through Eclipse?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to rename your form.html to index.php and run it by using url `http://localhost/Test/index.php` and you are done.

Please note that in "open with" means you want to open the file which is in your hard disk it doesnt mean run.

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a WAMP environment for your testing/development purposes.

Eclipse is providing you a shortcut to run the script but the HTTP server and PHP is not included.

Comment: I have XAMPP properly set up, that's not the issue.

Comment: Ok great, so your Eclipse project is not setup properly. In your project's settings you have to set how to run your project. You must enter to run your project as a local website on http://localhost